# Replace "onClick" with "after x seconds"

Tags: javascript, php

```
<div id="c" onClick="func()"></div>
```

This will execute funct() only when the user will click. But I want to execute func() automatically after 10 seconds. Somethink like this:

```
<div id="c" After10Seconds="func()"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write some logic. Use a flag and a `timeout` on the page load:

```
var hasCalledFunc = false;
setTimeout(function() {
    if (hasCalledFunc == false) func();
}, 10000);

function callFunc() {
    if (hasCalledFunc == false) func();
}

function func() {
    hasCalledFunc = true;
    //..rest of func
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="c" onClick="callFunc()"></div>
```

Or, all in `func`

```
var hasCalledFunc = false;
function func() {
    if (hasCalledFunc) return;
    else hasCalledFunc = true

    //rest of func
}

setTimeout(func, 10000);
```